# How can I output eslint errors to Metro bundler's console?

Tags: typescript, react-native, eslint, middleware, metro-bundler

I searched dozens and dozens of tutorials and threads but didn't find info about how can I do it.

I need something like eslint-webpack-plugin solution, like middleware or something. Something that will prevent to compile my code until I fix all eslint or typescript errors and warnings.

I know that metro.config.js has that enhancedMiddleware option, but I have no idea about what type of code should I put there to make it work. Google searches doesn't help.

Any information will be great, thank you.